Informativeness and entropy, Sims 2010 chapter 4
I have a potential very simple question for you, a little bit tough for me. I'm reading the chapter 4 of the famous handbook of economics by Woodford, where Sims is introducing the idea of the rational inattention. Since this is more related with information theory, I'm not used to this kind of math literature.
I would ask different questions about how to get the entropy and the informativeness of k-dimensional random vectors.  
Mr Sims claimed that the entropy of a k-dimensional $N(\mu,\Sigma)$ random vector is $\frac{1}{2}(log(2\pi)+log|\Sigma|+k)$. Thus "This means that the mutual information between two jointly normally distributed random vectors X and Y is half the difference between the log of the unconditional covariance matrix of Y and the log of the residual covariance matrix for a regression of Y on X. It depends only on the correlation matrix of X and Y, not on the levels of the variances themselves". 
Moreover, from this he derived that if X and Y are each one-dimensional, their mutual information is just $-\frac{1}{2}log(1-\rho^2)$ with $\rho$ correlation of X with Y. 
$X,Y\sim N(\mu, \Sigma)\Rightarrow I(X,Y)=\frac{1}{2}(-log|\Sigma|+log(Var(X))+log(Var(Y))=-\frac{1}{2}log(1-\rho_{XY}^2)$.

Could you please explain me the mathematical procedures that you have to do to show why the entropy of the k.dimensional random vector is like that if gaussian, and how the informativeness in the last row transforms from the sum in the huge brackets to the $1-\rho^2$? Thank you very much in advance.

Riccardo

Too much. You first need to understand  the concept of Shannon entropy (with discrete variables) and mutual information. Then, the (different) concept of differential entropy, and how it still allows to define a mutual information for continuos variables.
